# Don't postpone fixing the [delay] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [delay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delay) tag is undefined and used in several ways.  Many of the questions are about processing delays.  Some are about postponing activity.  Some are about external delays (like emails not being delivered in a timely fashion).  A couple are about adjusting audio or video timing.

Recommendation:

- [timing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timing) is an undefined tag that may eventually need cleanup but for now, it may be a good place for questions dealing with audio or video timing.  Alternative: create [audio-timing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-timing) and [video-timing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-timing) tags now.  (Could also create [presentation-timing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/presentation-timing) since there are many questions related to this under various other tags).
- There is an existing [scheduling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) tag that would work for some questions, but that is defined as relating to a specific time or event.  A number of questions deal with undefined postponement.  It wouldn't hurt to just create a [postpone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/postpone) tag.
- [delay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delay) could then be defined to mean processing or similar delays.  A [processing-delay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processing-delay) tag could be created, but I don't know that it would cover all of the remaining cases.